# C# App_Data class not inherited by aspx - inherits attribute question

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, inheritance, app-data

I have been trying to figure this out for a while now and even though there are plenty of Google results for the error message I receive the solution eludes me.  I think that I am doing what I am supposed to be doing.

VS2010, I created a common.cs in App_Data.  The content of common.cs are functions which will be used by all pages.  As far as I can tell this is the proper way to share code-behind code among multiple pages.

App_Data\common.cs

```
namespace nprah
{
    public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    }
{
```

fish-creek.aspx.cs

```
namespace nprah
{
    public partial class Fishck : BasePage
    {
    }
}
```

fish-creek.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="fish-creek.aspx.cs" Inherits="nprah.BasePage" %>
```

If I understand the Inherits attribute correctly then it does need to contain the NameSpace.ClassName, which mine does.  See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312311

When I run this code it results in the following output:

> Compiler Error Message: ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 11: {
>   Line 12:
>   Line 13:     public partial class Fishck : BasePage
>   Line 14:     {
>   Line 15:

Visual Studio is not showing any errors during the design.  Any guidance you may be able to provide will be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: might be a typo, but your aspx header says the codebehind file is 'fish-creek.aspx.cs' but your code snippet says 'fishck.aspx.cs'

Comment: yeah the file names were just typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your ASPX it should be

```
Inherits="nprah.Fishck"
```

Inherits in your .aspx should be mapping to your code file(.cs)... and from there your codefile will inherit your basepage like you already did.

And also try to validate that : CodeFile="fish-creek.aspx.cs".
Because with the name of the file you supplied it should be : Codefile="fishck.aspx.cs".
Maybe just a typo.

Comment: +1 for the "and also.." there seems to be a difference between the actual class name and the one requested in the aspx page

Comment: Thank you very much! I can't believe I overlooked the obvious as I was looking through the examples I found on google.  The file name mixup was indeed just a typo transferring it to SO.  Fixed it in the original question.